# Hotspot connectivity stops while on phone

Tags: calls, wifi-hotspot, htc-one

I have an HTC One M9 (Verizon). I regularly use the hotspot to give my laptop internet while commuting. However, I have noticed that while using hotspot, if I make or receive a phone call, internet connectivity through the hotspot stops (the laptop stays connected to the hotspot, but has no internet access) for the duration of the call, and is instantly restored the moment the call ends.

Why does this happen, and, if possible, how can it be fixed? I would like to be to use hotspot and make a phone call at the same time. My previous HTC One M8 (Verizon) did not suffer from this problem.

I also haven't been able to find much about this while Googling, though I can't tell if it's because my problem is rare or because the search terms are just too general.

(P.S. someone should make an `htc-one-m9` tag for the site)

Comment: CDMA networks like Verizon have trouble with simultaneous data and voice, though I've forgotten the details.

Comment: @MatthewRead I had no trouble with it with my old HTC One M8

Comment: This (hotspots disfunctioning while on phone call) happens with BSNL for me but not with Vodafone connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked @VZWSupport about it. They echoed what @Joe says, but also said that turning on "Advanced Calling" would enable SVLTE.

[See the conversation on Twitter](https://twitter.com/MattHerbst_/status/603604158097334272?cn=cmVwbHk%3D&refsrc=email)

Answer (score 1):

For what ever reason the M9 doesn't support SVLTE(simultaneous voice and LTE). The M8 did.